# magnetism in NMR spectroscopy

Tags: electromagnetism, fermions, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

How do electrons reduce the effective magnetic field felt by protons? This is the explanation given to chemical shift, how does it work?

Comment: You can see them as current around the chemically shifted nucleus. Inherent magnetic field cancel out in a sample.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry for my late reply. The H nucleus has access to two electrons that spin pair, I could be wrong but I assume these electrons will contribute equal and opposite magnetic fields. Shouldn't they cancel out? Also the explanation for chemical shift is changing the electron density around the nucleus due to the proximity of electron withdrawing groups. Thanks again for your help.